I have installed CUDA toolkit 11.8 and set the environmental variable and paths for it, yet I am facing this issue, when trying to install auto-gptq
(base) C:\Users\hells>conda activate finetune

(finetune) C:\Users\hells>pip install auto-gptq
Collecting auto-gptq
  Using cached auto_gptq-0.7.1.tar.gz (126 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hells\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ddr5t_1s\auto-gptq_90472a5ccf304fdd9e87ca9316d0d318\setup.py", line 125, in <module>
          cpp_extension.CUDAExtension(
        File "C:\Users\hells\.conda\envs\finetune\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1076, in CUDAExtension
          library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hells\.conda\envs\finetune\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1214, in library_paths
          paths.append(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hells\.conda\envs\finetune\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 2416, in _join_cuda_home
          raise OSError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
      OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
      conda_cuda_include_dir C:\Users\hells\.conda\envs\finetune\Lib\site-packages\nvidia/cuda_runtime/include
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I want to fine tune a pretrained model stored in my drive with a dataset.csv using transformers library (autotrain advanced didnt work for me) The model apparently requires auto-gptq for quantization and i am unable to install it and progress further. Please Help me.
